# How to filter 2 dimensional array and get number of duplicates into the unique row count

Tags: php

I have issue in which I have to count the number of defect in the array and also remove any duplication with respect to name and problem only not with cause.

I have tried using a loop to remove the duplicate value but I dont know how to update the Qty column with the number of repetitions.

I wanted to filter the below array with unique value and also count the number of repetitions in the array and enter it into top row as Qty.

```
I need the output like

SlNo     name     Problem     Qty
1.       Tata     brake        3
2.       xeq      fuel         2
3.       Shift    headlight    1

Can anyone help me out with this issue... Thanks


    <?PHP 
    $AryCars = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'Tata',
        'Problem' => 'brake',
        'Cause' => 'drum'
        'Qty' => '1'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'xeq',
        'Problem' => 'fuel',
        'Cause' => 'pump failure'
        'Qty' => '1'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'xeq',
        'Problem' => 'fuel',
        'Cause' => 'tank damage'
        'Qty' => '1'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'Tata',
        'Problem' => 'brake',
        'Cause' => 'oil leak'
        'Qty' => '1'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'name' => 'xeq',
        'Problem' => 'fuel',
        'Cause' => 'fuel'
        'Qty' => '1'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'name' => 'Tata',
        'Problem' => 'brake',
        'Cause' => 'damage'
        'Qty' => '1'
    ),
    5 => array(
        'name' => 'Shift',
        'Problem' => 'headlight',
        'Cause' => 'fuse'
        'Qty' => '1'
    )
    )

    ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your best effort, and we'll take it from there.

Comment: I'm most of the way there but must get back to work. Perhaps someone can continue: https://repl.it/repls/SphericalArtisticProgrammer